# Android: run an app from the command line for the first time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html), I have found these lines below when trying to run an app.

```
Run the app from a command line
-------------------------------

Open a command-line and navigate to the root of your project directory. Use Gradle to build your project in debug mode, invoke the assembleDebug build task using the Gradle wrapper script (gradlew assembleRelease).

This creates your debug .apk file inside the module build/ directory, named MyFirstApp-debug.apk.

On Windows platforms, type this command:

> gradlew.bat assembleDebug

On Mac OS and Linux platforms, type these commands:

$ chmod +x gradlew
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

So I have installed Gradle, and supposing that `gradle wrapper` is the same as `gradlew`, I have done the same steps, but when I try to run:

```
/MyFirstApp$ gradle wrapper assembleDebug
```

> FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'wrapper' not found in root project 'MyFirstApp'.
> - Try: Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.946 secs

This is the content of my `MyFirstApp` directory:

```
AndroidManifest.xml  bin        **gradlew**  local.properties      project.properties  src
ant.properties       build.xml  libs     proguard-project.txt  res
```

As you can see I have also `gradlew` command since I have copied from `/home/me/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew`. But when I try to run `./gradlew assembleDebug` I get this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Answer (score 0):

The command `gradle wrapper` actually sets up a directory (project) for building with gradle using the wrapper.  It fetches the wrapper script/executable and pulls a version of gradle locally into the directory (ok, a subdirectory.)  It's not the same as calling `gradlew` as `gradlew` is the wrapper itself.

Did you create your Android project using Android Studio?  It will have setup the wrapper for you and pre-populated the `build.gradle`, `settings.gradle` and other necessary files.

Comment: I have user this command to create the project `./android create project --target 1 --name MyFirstApp --path ~/workspace/android/MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp`. Just as it said in the docs, in the section "Create a Project with Command Line Tools". I don't want to use Android Studio.

Comment: Interesting.  It looks like that method of creating projects isn't up to date with the tools.  It creates a project layout for the old Eclipse/ant based style rather than gradle.  Android Studio is definitely where the focus is as far as tools go.  I recommend using it at least to setup your projects.  After the project has been created you can use vi, emacs, or whatever.  You may even find you like Android Studio enough to keep using it.  ;-)